Kube Controller Manager and Scheduler is restarting due to leader election
I used kubeadm to deploy Kubernetes on a single AWS EC2 machine, but I'm having trouble. The Kube Controller Manager keeps restarting because of the constant leader election.
I tried to disable leader election but not worked for me.
My Ec2 Machine SS
